# Artyom.js disables itself immedeately

Tags: javascript, html, css, voice-recognition

So I am having a couple of issues when using the voice library Artyom.js.
 I have tried adding my own commands, and in theory, that should work. But the major issue is that the voice recognition stops immediately after enabling it. The following are the javascript, css and html files:

```js
var five = require("johnny-five");
var keypress = require("keypress");

    const artyom = new Artyom();

function startArtyom() {
  artyom.initialize({
    lang:"en-GB",
    continous:true,
    debug:true,
    listen:true,
    speed:1,
    mode:"normal"
  }).then(function(){
    console.log("ready!");



  })
}

var commandHello = {
    indexes:["hello","good morning","hey"], // These spoken words will trigger the execution of the command
    action:function(){ // Action to be executed when a index match with spoken word
        artyom.say("Hey buddy ! How are you today?");
    }
};

artyom.addCommands([commandHello]);


/*keypress(process.stdin);*/

/*var board = new five.Board();*/
```

```css
body {
  font-family: ebrima;
}
#body{
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
#speech-cont {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 500px;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
  padding: 10px;
}

#speech-cont h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: ebrima;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

#speech-cont #box {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 0.5vh;
  background-color: white;
  height: 70%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-width: 1px;
}

#recognizeButton {
  height: auto;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>


<body id="body">
<div id="speech-cont">
<h3>Speech to text recognition</h3>

<div id="box">
<h4 id="result">
</h4>


</div>

<button id="recognizeButton" onclick="startArtyom();">Recognize!</button>
</div>
<script src="artyom.win.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see, I even straight up copy & pasted the example from Atryom.js' site to see if I had written a typo. Which turned out to not be the case.

I have absolutely no idea as to why artyom.js immediately stops voice recognition.

Thanks in advance :)